# Generator comprehension which adds different numbers of the same item

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

Given:

```
foo = (a,b,c,d,e,f)
multi = (b,d)
```

What generator comprehension gives the following tuple:

```
((a, None),
(b, True),
(b, False),
(c, None),
(d, True),
(d, False),
(e, None),
(f, None))
```

where items in `multi` appear twice with `True` and `False`, while other appear as `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested loop and pick one or the other iterable based on a membership test:

```
((v, other) for v in foo for other in ((True, False) if v in multi else (None,)))
```

The nested `for` loop version of the above is:

```
def gen():
    for v in foo:
        iterable = (True, False) if v in multi else (None,)
        for other in iterable:
            yield (v, other)
```